# How to override the default formfield for a read only foreign keys field in Django ModelAdmin?

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, django-admin, django-orm

I am overriding the default formfield of foreign keys on ModelAdmins as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey). However, I am not overriding it to return a subset, but instead to defer fields in order to optimize the performance. For example:

```py
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "car":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Car.objects.only("name")
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

It works for most of my use cases, but the problem occurres when the foreign key is set as a read only field. While debugging, I noticed that when it is set as read only, the field is never passed through `formfield_for_foreignkey` method and the query retrieving the foreign key selects all fields instead of only the necessary ones. In my case, some of the fields are too big causing an unecessary terrible performance.

I also tried the second method described in the docs, using `ModelForm.__init__()`, but it is not really useful for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am answering my own question. I haven't managed to solve what the issue presents, but I found a workaround that in my case achieves the same result.

Since the read-only foreign-key on Django Admin page is shown as a link, I did this:

```py
from django.utils.html import format_html
from django.urls import reverse

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    @admin.display(description="Car")
    def link_to_car(self, obj):
        link = reverse("admin:appname_car_change", args=[obj.car_id])
        return format_html('<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(link, Car.objects.all().only("name").get(id=obj.car_id)))

    fields = ("link_to_car")
    readonly_fields = ("link_to_car")
```

Well, as I said, it doesn't relate or solve the problem of overriding the formfield of a foreign key which is what I asked in the question, but it achieves the same result, showing the same thing while keeping the query optimized.

The only issue I had is having to write it in a kind of ugly way `Car.objects.all().only("name").get(id=obj.car_id)`, since simply writing `obj.car.name` would've initiate an extra query selecting everything from Car.